# How can I find out the name of the calling action in my MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to find out the action that called my view from within the view. Is there a simple way that I can do this without just passing the name to the view as part of the viewModel or viewData?

Comment: In general the view does not know anything about anything except for what it's displaying. Maybe if you can explain the problem that you are trying to solve, stack-overflowers might have a few alternative solutions for you to ponder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] 
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") // action
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") // controller
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can via the [ViewContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.aspx) RouteData property.

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```